# How to rectify versions on has_many/belongs_to association with paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations, has-many, paper-trail-gem

I use paper_trail in rails to track my models versions. But the documentation on the github repo indicates that the gem doesn't support `has_many`, `belongs_to` associations.

Let's say I've an app that records the ceos names of some comapnies:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ceos
  has_paper_trail
end

class Ceo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :companies
  has_paper_trail
end
```

The above example represent the information of ABC Inc.

```
company.name => "ABC"
company.ceo.past => "John Henry"
company.ceo.present =>  "Amy Warren"
```

How can I implement the following operation so it will reset the company and the company's ceos names to the last version?

Comment: Do you have any update on this?

Comment: I also have same issue

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to re-model the association to remove the has_many because in the case of CEOs, a company may have_many CEOs through its life, but it only has_one CEO for a certain period.

The implementation of this might be a has_one to a join table made up of the ID of both CEO and Company, and the time periods it was valid for.

A beneficial side effect is it would become trivial to have a person be CEO of a company 2 times with another CEO in between and have easy traversal of that in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for how to handle this can be found in the README: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/README.md#associations

Basically  will need to create a `version_associations` table, either at installation time with the `rails generate paper_trail:install --with-associations` option or manually for this to work.

I suggest you read the full documentation on Github for details on how this works.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.  You just have copied and pasted the poorly written instructions on this topic.

Comment: @dane Maybe you can help me, and others, by editing the question and make it clearer what it is that the OP is asking for then?